# How do I scrape a specific table from a web page and display it in Excel? The table goes horizontally?

Tags: python, html, excel, web-scraping, html-table

I am trying to scrape information from the tables at this website [>>Here<<](http://espn.go.com/golf/leaderboard?tour=pga)
I want to be able to get the scores when I want, I want to be able to get it and export it into Excel, also, I would like the data to come under the hole no. as well. The data that I want is wrapped in a `<table>` tag with a class of "scoreboard", that is the bit that I want. I would also like the players name.

Is this possible, if so how?

Please answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel has its own *import data from website* feature. It has a nice GUI and can let you easily make dynamic web queries in your excel sheet so that the data will update every time you open the book. This might be the easiest and most efficient way for you to go.

[Scrappy](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is much better, especially for larger projects, for use in python, but if your going to put it back into Excel it might not be worth the extra effort.

Check out the official Excel docs on creating dynamic web queries [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/get-external-data-from-a-web-page-HA010218472.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna take a look at [Scrapy](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It's a web scraper framework written in Python. It's powerful and easily extensible and customizable.